# Need to know how to remove a certain item from a players inventory in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

Im currently able to detect an item in a players inventory and it is only active if the player is holding it while pressing the button that activates the chosen item. But I've been trying to get a chained, conditional, Always active block after it to remove the item after pressing the button. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes:

By using the /clear command you can clear an item from a players inventory `/clear @p <or> (playername) (item name)`  For an example `/clear @p minecraft:dirt`

Comment: The issue with this is that the item is very specific, the command i used to summon it is

/give @p beetroot 1 0 {display:{Name:"Heart of Asmodeus"
Lore:["Heart of the Ruler of the Fire Plane.","It is said to have been taken by the Archangel Gallaldriel."]},HideFlags:6,Unbreakable:1}                           

Will that effect this at all?

Comment: @MercedFlores Yes, `/clear` supports dataTags. You can check the [wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#clear) for command syntax. However, I recommend you to use custom NBT data instead of trying to detect every single tag on the item for simplification (e.g. `/give @p stone 1 0 {specialStone:1b,display:{Name:"Test"}}` with `/clear @p stone -1 -1 {specialStone:1b}`).

Comment: So is there no way to keep the Lore on the Item? And is it possible to give it an enchantment so it has a glowing effect?

Comment: @MercedFlores The "specialStone" tag just represents all the data as a whole so you don't have to retype it all in `/clear`. Add whatever you want to the `/give` command.